# Logout hyperlink within a sub-menu

Tags: functions, menus, admin-menu, sub-menu, menu-order

I have the following secondary navigation menu on my website which has been built using the native *WordPress Appearance > Menus* feature:

[image: secondary navigation menu]

---

I am also using the following lines of code in my **functions.php** file to remove and add the '*Login / Register*' and '*Logout*' hyperlinks depending on the access privileges of the user:

```
// Add a Login hyperlink to the secondary navigation menu if the user is logged-out
function wpa_remove_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if( is_admin() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $items;

    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( 'Login / Register' == $item->title ) unset( $items[$key] );
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa_remove_menu_item', 10, 3 );


// Remove the Logout hyperlink from the secondary navigation menu when the user is logged-in
function wpa_add_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return $items;

    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( 'Logout' == $item->title ) unset( $items[$key] );
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa_add_menu_item', 10, 3 );
```

Which is output like so:

[image] [image]

---

The *Logout* menu item is using the following hyperlink:

[image]

How can I replace this URL so that when the user selects the *Logout* item in the secondary navigation menu, it does not redirect them to a confirmation screen...

[image]

and is still positioned within the same hierarchy (within the '*My Account*' parent menu of the '*Secondary Header*', not at the start or end of the entire menu)?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but it might work, use `wp_logout_url()` wordpress in built function to get logout url.

```
// Add a Login hyperlink to the secondary navigation menu if the user is logged-out
function wpa_remove_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if( is_admin() || ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $items;

    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( 'Login / Register' == $item->title ) unset( $items[$key] );
        if ( 'Logout' == $item->title ){$items[$key]->url=wp_logout_url();}
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa_remove_menu_item', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can log someone out without using the standard logout page via the [`wp_logout`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout) function.

Here's an example that will work if you're using pretty permalinks, which hooks the `parse_query` action, checks if the requested URL is `logout`, and if so logs the user out and redirects them to the home page-

```
function wpd_logout( $query ){
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['pagename'] )
    && $query->query_vars['pagename'] == 'logout' ):
        wp_logout();
        wp_redirect( home_url('/') );
        exit;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_logout' );
```

Comment: Hi there Milo, could you please provide me with some assistance in implementing your suggestion?  I have pasted this into the functions.php file and have activated the pretty permalinks setting.

Comment: it's the same as your current code, just change the URL of your logout menu item to `/logout/`

Comment: Hi there Milo, just to clarify what I have - http://i.stack.imgur.com/johBZ.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/9BZ9q.png.  This redirects to a page that does not exist and keeps the user logged-in.

Comment: is your WordPress install in the root of your domain?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Comment: then the link should point to wherever the root of your WP site is located, like `/some-directory/logout/`

Comment: **/** > **public_html** > **sd** > **wp-content** > **themes** > **sd**

Comment: URL, not server path